# mysql, order-by, check if and item is included in another table first

Tags: php, mysql, join, sql-order-by

**MySQL:**

table1

```
+--------+-------+
| itemid | title |
+--------+-------+
|   1    | title |
+--------+-------+
```

table2

```
+----+--------+------------+
| id | itemid |    time    |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |    1   | 1295116368 |
+----+--------+------------+
|  1 |    2   | 1295548368 |
+----+--------+------------+
|  2 |    1   | 1294079568 |
+----+--------+------------+
```

**PHP:**

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT `itemid` FROM `table2` WHERE `id` = '1' ORDER BY `time` DESC")
while($b = mysql_fetch_assoc($a))
{
    echo $b['itemid'].'<br />';
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
1
```

However, what I want to do in the query above is to also check whether itemid is also included in **table1**, because when it is I want it to show up first, despite the fact that it might be an older post.

I hope this makes sense.

So, the output should be:

```
1
2
```

because itemid = 1, is also included in table1.

Comment: You should avoid using identical ids like you are. It's illogical to have an identifier that does not identify anything uniquely. If you try to use an ORM that expects, reasonably, id to be a primary key, it will blow up because you have duplicates. That said, I think Sam Dufel has the right idea for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you should be able to join the tables and sort by the title

```
SELECT itemid FROM table2
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (itemid) 
WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY title DESC, time DESC
```

You may have to flip the sorting on title, I don't remember if NULL values are sorted at the beginning or end.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
SELECT `itemid` FROM `table2` t2 LEFT JOIN `table1` t1
ON t2.itemid = t1.itemid WHERE t2.`id` = '1' ORDER BY t1.itemid, t2.`time` DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join to table1 with a left join and then first order by table1's item_id and then by the time on table2:

```
  SELECT  t2.item_id
  FROM    table2 t2 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
  WHERE   t2.id = 1
  ORDER BY IFNULL(t1.item_id, 'a') ASC, t2.time DESC
```

NOTE: I use the IFNULL in the order by clause to cause NULL values to be ordered last.

Comment: +1 I think the IFNULL is important. Otherwise the result set will not be ordered as the OP was hoping.